# I can't run something that I can run in servlet with the same logic in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

When I press the Roles button in the photo, I want each role to have its own permissions to the photo below. In the photo below, each role should have its own permissions. I tried to try but I just can't. The thing is, I could only do this using logic in the servlet application, but I can't do it in jsp either, because there are some rules that jsp shouldn't have java codes.[image]

[image]

1)I take all the roles and post them to my jsp page and output there in each td tag, it works fine.
[image]

2)This is my servlet controller side.

```
@WebServlet(name = "RoleListController", urlPatterns = {"/admin/rolelist"})
public class RoleListController extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Object userObject = session.getAttribute("user");
        User user = (User) userObject;

        if (user != null) {
            request.setAttribute("admin_url", request.getContextPath() + "/admin/admin-panel");
            request.setAttribute("home_url", request.getContextPath() + "/home");
            request.setAttribute("employeelist_url", request.getContextPath() + "/private/employee-list");
            request.setAttribute("insert_url", request.getContextPath() + "/private/insert");
            request.setAttribute("edit_url", request.getContextPath() + "/private/edit-employee-page");
            request.setAttribute("delete_url", request.getContextPath() + "/private/delete-employee-page");
            request.setAttribute("login_url", "login");
            request.setAttribute("register_url", "register");

            RoleDaoService rsd = new RoleDaoManager();
            UserDaoService usd = new UserDaoManager();
            PermissionDaoService pds = new PermissionDaoManager();

            List<Permission> permissions = pds.findAll();

            int roleId = usd.findRoleIdByUserId(user.getId());

            List<Integer> permissionsId = rsd.findPermissionIdByRoleId(roleId);

            //roles are obtained here.
            List<Role> roles = rsd.findAll();
            //and the attribute is sent to jsp
            request.setAttribute("roles", roles);
            
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/rolepage.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

3)Here is the part I just made using servlet and it works, but I can't do it in jsp.

```
roles.forEach (r  
        -> {
                    out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>" + r.getName() + "</td>");
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println("<select name=role-permission>");
        permissions.forEach(p -> {
            List<RolePermission> rolePermissions = rolePermissionDaoService.findRoleAndPermissionId(r.getId(), p.getId());

            rolePermissions.forEach(rp -> {
                out.println("<option value=" + rp.getPageName() + " >" + rp.getPageName() + "</option>");
            });
        });
        out.println("</select>");
        out.println("</td>");

        if (r.getStatus() == UserStatusEnum.CONFIRMED.getValue()) {
            out.println("<td><span class=\"status text-success\">&bull;</span>Active</td>");
        } else {
            out.println("<td><span class=\"status text-success\">&bull;</span>Deactive</td>");
        }
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println("<a href=" + request.getContextPath() + "/admin/edit-role?id=" + r.getId() + " class=\"settings\" title=\"Settings\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\"><i class=\"material-icons\">&#xE8B8;</i></a>");
        out.println("<a href=\"#\" class=\"delete\" title=\"Delete\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\"><i class=\"material-icons\">&#xE5C9;</i></a>");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
    }

);
```

Comment: What does "can't do it" in JSP look like?  Error messages might help clarify.

Comment: According to MVC rules, there should be no java codes in jsp, so I don't want to do what I showed in section 3 above in jsp. What I want is how I can do what I showed in the 3rd part in jsp. I want to get help. Also, I don't get any errors, but this time it shows the permissions for all roles.

Comment: "MVS rules" - are those like speeding laws?  You should know a few things: (1) JSP is a 90s technology that has failed.  They aren't used much anymore.  (2) JSPs are templates that are used to generate HTML on the server side and stream the output to the browser.   Users only see the generated HTML, not the template code.

Comment: Anyway, I just shared the part I wanted to do so maybe it helps.

Comment: Please explain "can't do".  The code you posted looks like it would lend itself well to a JSTL-based JSP.  Why can't you do it?

Comment: anyway,I don't think it will be solved by explaining it here. Because it is a long issue and cannot be solved by commenting.

Comment: @mammadov1501 did you get a chance to review my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your view layer JSP page should only be responsible for rendering the roles data. It should not be using any DAO services to make direct calls to the database. So, your `RolePermission` lookup should happen in your controller layer servlet before dispatching the request to the JSP page.

**RoleListController**

```
List<Role> roles = rsd.findAll();
Map<Role, List<RolePermission>> rolePermissionsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

roles.forEach (r -> {
    List<RolePermission> rolePermissionsList = new ArrayList<>();
    permissions.forEach(p -> {
        List<RolePermission> rolePermissions =
                rolePermissionDaoService.findRoleAndPermissionId(r.getId(), p.getId());
        if (rolePermissions != null) {
            rolePermissionsList.addAll(rolePermissions);
        }
    });
    rolePermissionsMap.put(r, rolePermissionsList);
});

request.setAttribute("rolePermissionsMap", rolePermissionsMap);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/rolepage.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Notice the use of `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the same order as that of `List<Role> roles`.

The JSP page can now simply use nested `<c:forEach>` tags to iterate the `rolePermissionsMap` entries first and then for each `role` entry print all the mapped `rolePermission`s as select `<options>`.

**rolepage.jsp**

```
<c:forEach var="rolePermissions" items="${rolePermissionsMap}">
    <c:set var="role" value="${rolePermissions.key}" />
    <c:set var="rolePermissionsList" value="${rolePermissions.value}" />
    <tr>
        <td>${role.name}</td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-select" name="role-permission">
                <c:forEach var="rolePermission" items="${rolePermissionsList}">
                    <option value="${rolePermission.pageName}">${rolePermission.pageName}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <i class="fas fa—circle green"> ${role.status eq 1 ? 'Active' : 'Deactive'}</i>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/edit-role?id=${role.id}">
                <i class="fas fa—cog fa—lg me—2 edit"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-times-circle fa—cog fa—lg delete"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```